# Can my iPhone app host a Local Web server and allow other apps to the phone to access the LWS?

Tags: iphone, http, cocoahttpserver

I will use one of the following cocoahttpserver or iPhoneHTTPServer3, SimpleWebSocketServer, MultithreadedHTTPServer3 to host a server in my app.

Iam aware that a built-in apache is not possible..

Can other apps in the phone make http request to this server hosted locally.

Thanks,
--srihari

Comment: yes, they can, as long as your app is working properly in background.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how this can be achieved?? as i understand when the apps goes into the background state, it would go into a suspend state, one way we can achieve background is to call the beginbackgroundTaskWithexpirationhandler so that the specific thread keeps running for a finite-length time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done in a wired way. Cause apple doesn't allow app runing in background offically, however there's one exception that playing music in background is allowed, so you can keep your app running in background with playing a mp3 infinitely. However this is only a workaround, it would consume all your battery quickly.